# How to remove elements from list using lrange in TCL

Tags: unix, tcl, tclsh

Suppose i have list defined below

> list = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

how i can get below output -

> `list = {a,b,c,d,g,h}`

using lrange in tcl???

Comment: Why the requirement for `lrange`? It's much easier to do using `lreplace`.

Comment: `lrange` selects a contiguous sublist so can't remove chunks by itself; `lreplace` swaps a contiguous sublist for another (possibly empty) sequence of elements, so it can delete stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
set list [list a b c d e f g h]
```

Using [`lrange`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lrange.htm), we also need [`concat`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/concat.htm) to join the sublists together

```
set newlist [concat [lrange $list 0 3] [lrange $list 6 end]]  ;# => a b c d g h
```

But as @SchelteBron comments, [`lreplace`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lreplace.htm) is much simpler

```
set newlist [lreplace $list 4 5]                              ;# => a b c d g h
```

---

If the range to remove is not fixed, you can do:

```
set start 4
set stop 5
set newlist [lreplace $list $start $stop]
```

or

```
set start 4
set count 2
set newlist [lreplace $list $start [expr {$start + $count - 1}]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot glenn !!!

Comment: I see you've never accepted an answer to any of your questions. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)